# Short story about a human scientist that gets caught up in the ebb and flow of an alien environment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was part of a collection of short stories from the late 70s early 80s.  The aliens were jelly-like creatures filled with gasses.  The human scientist tries to save a certain group of aliens but winds up failing and by doing so understanding that the death and rebirth are all part of the planetary process.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this story? Was it written in English, where was it set? Any details about the anthology - e.g. was it a collection of works by a single author or with a single theme?

Comment: Hi yes, it was english, multiple authors I believe.

Answer (score 3):

A Meeting with Medusa? Arthur C. Clarke. The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Meeting_with_Medusa) for this novella says,

> Taking place partly on Earth and partly in the atmosphere of Jupiter,
> the story tells of Howard Falcon, the captain of a new and
> experimental giant-sized helium-filled airship. When an accident
> causes the ship to crash, Falcon is badly injured and takes over a
> year to fully recover.
>
> Later, Falcon promotes an expedition to explore the atmosphere of
> Jupiter. After several years and many trials, the expedition is
> launched, with Falcon at the controls of the Kon-Tiki, a hot-hydrogen
> balloon-supported craft that descends through the upper atmosphere of
> Jupiter.
>
> As the craft descends through the various cloud layers, Falcon
> discovers that the atmosphere supports at least two large forms of
> life, as well as microscopic and bioluminescent air plankton,
> producing atmospheric sea-fire. One form is a giant jellyfish-like
> creature (the Medusa of the title) about a mile across, and the others
> are manta ray-like creatures about a hundred yards wide that
> apparently prey on the Medusa.
>
> The Medusa begins to show an interest in the Kon-Tiki, and for his own
> and the expedition's safety, Falcon ignites his emergency power and
> escapes back into the upper atmosphere.
>
> After his return, it is revealed to the reader that because of the
> airship accident much of Falcon's body was replaced by prosthetics,
> making him a cyborg with increased speed and reactions - allowing him
> to venture further into deep space than anyone, while leaving him
> feeling distanced from other humans.

Check out its publication history [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56729).

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the description given in the question?